# How can a component be rendered conditionally dependent upon the value in a defaultprops array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a ReactJS `static defaultProps` array, which is used to render a number of buttons. I'm looking to conditionally generate a text-component dependent upon which specific button is clicked.

Here is an example depicting a `Car` component:

```
...
static defaultProps = {
   cars: [
      { type: 'hatchback', color: 'red', info: '...' },
      { type: 'sedan', color: 'blue', info: '...' },
      { type: '4x4', color: 'green', info: '...' },
   ]
}
...
```

Let us say that each 'type' field generates a button labelled with `type`. Let's imagine that I want to create a swatch div that depicts the color `onClick`. So if I click the `'hatchback'` button, then the swatch div will turn `'green'` or `'red'` or `'blue'`, dependent upon the car `type` selected.

### What is the easiest way to do this?

Here is an example of the button mapping function:

```
{this.props.cars.map((car) => (
   <button>
      {car.type}
   </button>
```

And here would be an example of the `colorSwatch` div:

```
<div className={styles.colorSwatch}>{car.info}</div>
```

To be as specific as possible, the problem is to do with the text content and not conditional CSS issues.

I want to know how to conditionally set `info`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the clicked button object in state and use it to render your colorSwatch div

```
{this.props.cars.map((car) => (
   <button onClick={() => this.setState({clickedBtn: car})}>
      {car.type}
   </button>

const { clickedBtn } = this.state;
...
{clickedBtn && <div className={styles.colorSwatch}>{clickedBtn.info}</div>}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm still going through your code to make sure I fully understand the logic flow. An elegant solution!